# storing row numbers only in array using VBA

Tags: arrays, vba

I was just wondering if there is a short and simple way to store the row number of cell location into an array.  I have only been to store the entire cell location using the '.Address' vba function but I don't want the columns referenced so I can maniuplate the arrays later on in my sub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the row of a range, you can use the `row` property :

```
Dim myCell as Range
Dim myRow as Long
myRow = myCell.row
```

You can, of course, store the row in an array.

By the way, here are some tips about rows and columns : http://www.exceltip.com/excel_tips/Cells,_Ranges,_Rows,_and_Columns_in_VBA/204.html

Regards,

Max

Comment: Thanks JMax, but wouldn't that tell you how many rows are in the range rather than tell you which row a value is within a range?

Comment: the `rows` property contains every row of the range. Hence, `rows.count` is the number of rows of your range. If you want to get the index of each row in an array, i think you will have to loop over the `rows` (for each... next)

Comment: Max,In VBA you should always use Long rather than Integer when referring to rows to prevent Overflow. VBA integer only holds up to 32768.

Comment: @Charles Williams: thanks for this tip. i'll edit my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Sub HTH()

Dim rCell As Range
Dim vMyArray() As Variant
Dim iLoop As Integer

For Each rCell In Range("A1:A10")
    ReDim Preserve vMyArray(iLoop)
    vMyArray(iLoop) = rCell.Row
    iLoop = illop + 1
Next rCell

End Sub
```